# Git server hooks

Tags: git, hook, githooks

How can I run a hook on server when sending data to git repository? (When I start the push command from client -> git push origin master)

The steps that I have done so far:

- I've created a `post-receive` file in the `hooks` folder on the server (`GitServer/GitRepository.git/hooks/post-receive`)
- I changed the `post-receive` file to be executable (with `chmod +x post-receive`)
- I have debugged the `post-receive` hook manually - no problem, and perform the manual start everything correctly

Comment: Suggest that you modify the post-receive so that it returns a non-zero code, which should block the update. Then you'll be able to tell if it's being called or not and debug further. Also check it's executable by every user, not just yours, and the hooks directory has `rx` bits set for all.